# get the container class name (UIView Type)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following UIView structure:

```
UIView A contains UIView B
UIView B contains UIView C
UIView C contains UIView D
```

In Objective C, is it possible to get the UIView Class instance A from UIView D to access an instance method of A from D?

Comment: are those subclass/superclasses of each other or subview/superviews?

Comment: @sanver, you don't understand the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the following code to get access a instance method of A from D. Actually following this I got an instance of A object from D. And Here A is the superview of D Object.

```
-(void)getTheSpecificSuperView
{
    BOOL found = FALSE;
    UIView *currentSuperView = self; // right now it is D

    while (!found) {
        if ([[currentSuperView superview] isKindOfClass:[A class]]) {
            found = TRUE;
            A *a = (A *)[currentSuperView superview];
            [a accessAnInstanceMethod];
        }
        else{
            currentSuperView = [currentSuperView superview];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know for sure that this will be your situation in all situations, you can do the following from View D:

```
[self.superview.superview.superview instanceMethod:anArgument]; // Ew.
```

If you know that View A is somewhere higher up in the view hierarchy, but you don't know exactly where you can loop through the superviews until you find it. You just need something to identify the view by. E.g. you can set View A's `tag` property to a number (let's say `42`) and find it that way:

```
UIView *sup = self.superview;
while (sup.tag != 42) {  
    sup = sup.superview; // Keep going up the hierarchy until you find a match.
}

[sup instanceMethod:anArgument];
```

**Note:** this code is super unsafe. Only use if you're certain it's somewhere up there in the hierarchy.

See also [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW13) in the docs.

Comment: oh! thanks a lot. :-) I have already found a way without setting tag. But your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Try,

```
UIView *refView = [[[D superView] superView] superView];
```

Now check

```
if([refView isEqualTo:refView]){
   NSLog(@"I am A");
}
```